# How to detect escape characters looping through string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, html-escape-characters

I have a scenario where I need to format a string into an array to display it in a different way to the user. So, when I get an escape character (for a new line) `\n` I need to add that as a separate array item.

Example string : `sampe\nanother sample HERE\n\n\nfinal`

Should be formatted to `["sample", "another sample", "", "", "final"]`

Here the empty strings in the array are for the new lines.
How can I achieve this ?

**EDIT** :  I have a special scenario if something in between `${`, `}` that also should be considers as a new array item.

eg : `"sampe\n${abc}another sample HERE\n\n\nfinal"`
in this case, this should be the array
`["sample", "${abc}", "another sample", "", "", "final",]`

So, this should also be achievable . Currently without considering the escape characters I'm looping through the array to detect `${` and `}` to do this. So, with the `\n` how can I get this work

Comment: `string.split("\n")` ? but if you really want to "loop through" the string ... just check if the character is equal to `"\n"`

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you. This works.But I updated the question for the special scenario. That's why I was trying looping through it

Comment: well then, loop through the string looking for the characters you want now that you know what to look for

Comment: @JaromandaX maybe a regular expression is a better choice than than manually implementing a loop through the string.

Comment: @WildernessRanger - maybe, but that's beyond the scope of the question

Answer (score 0):

Just as @JaromandaX commented, you can use `string.split("\n")` to break your string into an array.
For the `${...}` scenario, you can try `string.matchAll(/\$\{.*?\}/g)` to find these sequences in the string (change `.*` if you want to restrict the content inside), and then you can split the string using `Array.prototype.reduce()` like:

```
// Find and convert all the matches to an array
let matches = Array.from(string.matchAll(/\$\{.*?\}/g));

let result = matches.reduce((res, mat) => {
    res.array.push(string.substring(res.last, mat.index), mat[0]); // each match makes 2 more segments
    res.last = mat.index + mat[0].length; // next segment begins after the match
    return res;
// Use an array to store result and an integer to record where the segment begins
}, {array: [], last: 0});

// Put the remaining segment into result
result.array.push(string.substring(result.last));

// Keep only the segments array as that's the result cared
result = result.array;
```